# Facebook comments is not showing up in my Facebook profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I have implemented Facebook comment for my site and the comments are now showing up in my Facebook profile? How to solve this?

Comment: You mean "comments are NOT showing up in my Facebook profile", right?

Comment: Yes, i implemented in my site and few of my friends posted a comment there. And it is not showing up in their profiles

Answer (score 0):

Facebook comments will not show up on your personal Facebook profile by default. If everything is setup correctly, the comments moderation tool can be accessed from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments